# Maximizing a function that contain a binomial coefficient term?

Tags: probability, optimization, binomial-coefficients, special-functions, non-convex-optimization

I am an electrical engineer and I am interested in maximizing an objective function that contains a binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}
 = \frac{{n!}}{{\left( {n - k} \right)!k!}}$.

This is a follow up question from a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807472/probability-that-the-row-in-the-table-contain-only-one-bit-one/4808043?noredirect=1#comment10229441_4808043).

The problem can be stated as:

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\mathop {{\rm{Max}}}\limits_{} }&{m \times \sum\limits_{k = 2}^{k = n} {\left[ {\left( {1 - {{\left( {1 - kq{p^{n - 1}}} \right)}^{m - 1}}} \right)\binom{n}{k}{q^k}{p^{n - k}}} \right]} }\\
{{\rm{s.t:}}}&{p = 1 - q}\\
{}&{0 \le p \le 1}\\
{}&{m,n \in Z}
\end{array}$

From this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4073822/are-binomial-coefficients-defined-for-k-in-mathbbr), it seems that the binomial coefficient can be thought of as some kind of gamma function but this gamma function is so strange and I am not sure if its derivative even exists:

$\binom{n}{k}:=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}$

**Case 1**: $n$ is a known parameter, $m$ and $p$ are decision variables.

**Case 2**: $m$ is a known parameter, $n$ and $p$ are decision variables.
I think case 2 is very difficult, it looks like some sort of online optimization problem.

**Case 3**: Both $m$ and $n$ are known parameters, $p$ or $q$ is a decision variable. I think this case might be easier.

**Case 4**: Both $m$ and $p$ are known parameters, $n$ is a decision variable.

Effort so far for **case 3**: this case is quite complicated than it looks, I have set $m=n$ for simplicity and optimize the variable $q$. Since this problem has only one variable $q$, I have taken the derivative of the objective function and recive the following

$f'\left( q \right) = n\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\left( {{q^k}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\
k
\end{array}} \right)\left( { - k{n^2}q{{(1 - q)}^{n - 2}}{{\left( {1 - kq{{(1 - q)}^{n - 1}}} \right)}^{n - 2}} - kq{{(1 - q)}^{n - 2}}{{\left( {1 - kq{{(1 - q)}^{n - 1}}} \right)}^{n - 2}} - k{{(1 - q)}^{n - 1}}{{\left( {1 - kq{{(1 - q)}^{n - 1}}} \right)}^{n - 2}} + kn{{(1 - q)}^{n - 1}}{{\left( {1 - kq{{(1 - q)}^{n - 1}}} \right)}^{n - 2}} + 2knq{{(1 - q)}^{n - 2}}{{\left( {1 - kq{{(1 - q)}^{n - 1}}} \right)}^{n - 2}}} \right){{(1 - q)}^{n - k}} + k{q^{k - 1}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\
k
\end{array}} \right)\left( {1 - {{\left( {1 - kq{{(1 - q)}^{n - 1}}} \right)}^{n - 1}}} \right){{(1 - q)}^{n - k}} + {q^k}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\
k
\end{array}} \right)\left( {1 - {{\left( {1 - kq{{(1 - q)}^{n - 1}}} \right)}^{n - 1}}} \right)\left( {k{{(1 - q)}^{ - k + n - 1}} - n{{(1 - q)}^{ - k + n - 1}}} \right)} \right)}$

Now, I cannot solve $f'\left( q \right) = 0$

Would you kindly help me with this ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: When binomial coefficients are involved, it might be a good idea to look at consecutive quotients instead of derivatives.

Comment: What is this consecutive quotient ? Could you kindly explain your idea to me ?

Comment: I was not looking to hard into the problem, but what i meant was to look at the ratio f(k)/f(k+1), where f is the function to maximize. I do not know whether this will bring something when a sum is involved.